# Typo3 File Download (CSV) error

Tags: php, csv, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I'm generating a csv file out of my Typ3 extension, but in my csv file there are some mysterious lines.

```
<p><strong>Sorry, the requested view was not found.</strong></p>                    
<p>The technical reason is: <em>No template was found. View could not be resolved for action "exportPrueflinge" in class "ReRe\Rere\Controller\ExportController"</em>.</p>
```

My code looks like this:

From my Controller I call a helper Class with this code:

```
public function genCSV($array, $filename) {
    // Anlegen eine termporären datei mit Schreibrechten
    $fp = null;
    $fp = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

    // Array in CSV übertragen
    foreach ($array as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields, ";");
    }
    rewind($fp);
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $filename . '";');
    // Download starten
    fpassthru($fp);
}
```

what can I do to avoid the two wrong lines ? They are at the end of the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `return FALSE;` at the end of your genCSV() function, then the template rendering error message will not be added to your CSV file.

Comment: such easy! ... Thanks a lot! works fine! But the 'return false;'  must be in the controller

Answer (score 0):

This will sound like a bit of a dirty way of dealing with this, but try to just create the view template called : exportPrueflinge.html in Templates/Export.

Comment: don't have a view for this list. 

I collect the needed data from repository and then I write the csv file. 

or should I write the content in a plain view?

Comment: but I don't want that the csv file will be displayed ... I only want to download it